# Regex: grab contents of a JS function assigned to a property

Tags: regex

I need to grab only the contents of this function as a string:

```
(lib.foobar = function(mode, startPosition, loop) {
    // contents to grab
}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.foobar, new cjs.Rectangle(0, 0, 59.7, 59.4), null);
```

I got as far as this, but unable to exclude everything up until the opening curly brace: `foobar = function(mode, startPosition, loop) {`:

`(?={).*(?=})` [(view on Regexr)](https://regexr.com/3ohdk)

`(?=foobar.+{).+(?=})` [(view on Regexr)](https://regexr.com/3ohdn)

Comment: In general, you should not use regex to parse a programming language.

Comment: `(?<={).*(?=})`. Lookbehind syntax is `(?<=)`

Comment: @chrisz, it seems to work fine as the .* is greedy. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0mwm5i/1)

Comment: @chrisz you're right but we have no choice here - unless we get our hands on the code that generates the EaselJS animation coming out of Adobe Animate CC upon export.

Comment: You can't with JS. It's tough with other featured regex flavors too. Not recommended with Regular Expressions. You need to be aware about braces which denote a block of code, comments within block of code, braces within a quoted string and so many on. Just not possible with JS.

Comment: @Matt.G JS doesn't support lookbehinds. Only latest versions of Google Chrome support it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the regex:

```
(?:(?!foobar.*\n)\n)(?:.*\n)*(?=})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4py6yz/2)

Comment: Interesting solution. Thanks!